# OpenProcess fails for win 7

Tags: winapi, windows-7

I am using OpenProcess function. The code works perfectly fine in windows XP but fails on win 7 X32 bit.

My code is as follows

```
void SetDebugPrivileges()
{
    void* tokenHandle;

    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES privilegeToken;
    LookupPrivilegeValue(0, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &privilegeToken.Privileges[0].Luid);
    privilegeToken.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    privilegeToken.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &tokenHandle);
    AdjustTokenPrivileges(tokenHandle, 0, &privilegeToken, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), 0, 0);
    CloseHandle(tokenHandle);
}

HANDLE _stdcall MyOpenProcess(DWORD dwAccess, BOOL bInherit, DWORD dwPID)
{
    SetDebugPrivileges();

   HANDLE hRes = OpenProcess(dwAccess | PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, bInherit, dwPID);
}
```

OpenProcess fails with error code 5 on win 7 but works fine on XP. It would be great if anyone could help with this issue.

Comment: just to be sure.. you are running your application with administration rights?

Comment: Access denied.  Both VM_READ and debug access are very privileged.

Answer (score 4):

Most probably this is UAC-related. Are `OpenProcessToken` and `AdjustTokenPrivileges` actually successful?

Comment: Yes OpenProcessToken and AjustTokenPrivileges both functions are successfull.. I still get access denied error

Comment: Ok i noticed that when i run a particular installable i get the process Id of msiexec mutiple time in the MyOpenProcess function. I get it 5 times. So 5 times the openProcess is working on msiexec.exe. In which 4 times GetLastError() returns success and the 5th time it returns access denied. would that be the issue? Do i need to take care if i call openProcess multiple times?

Comment: Can you please add some more details to your original post, explaining what exactly you want to do and when exactly the issue occurs? How exactly does this relate to MSI's and msiexec.exe, when are you calling `MyOpenProcess()`, et cetera, et cetera.